# Enum, How to rename during (de)serialization?

Tags: java, jackson

Hi is it possible to change name of ENUM in Java?
For example, I have enum -

```
public enum CloudType {
    AZURE, OPENSTACK
}
```

And a class -

```
public class Env{
   private CloudType cloudType;
}
```

And during JACKSON parsing, if I give -

```
{
  "cloudType":"AZURE"
}
```

Or

```
{
  "cloudType":"azure"
}
```

It will give me an `Env` object with `cloudType=AZURE` ?

One thread is there ([Jackson databind enum case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157817/jackson-databind-enum-case-insensitive)), but really we need to do this much?
Or

```
@XmlEnumValue("azure")
    AZURE("azure"),
```

will be enough?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: That's not changing the name of an enum, is it? It's just assigning a value to an enum variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson databind enum case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157817/jackson-databind-enum-case-insensitive)

Comment: tl;dr : `MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS`

Comment: Actually I am doing serialization directly from REST request body which is capable of handling both Json & XML

Comment: Hi, kindly please clarify the question, you are asking for more different things, or there are just missing some clues? 
Eg. How to rename during (de)serialization ?

Because the correct answer can be like `Right click in your IDE to enum / class name and choose refactor - change name` ... 

Kindly please follow [mcve] and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) At this point, its unclear what are you asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can decouple the Java names of the `enum` instances from their JSON representations.

You should add a [`@JsonValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html)-annotated method to your `enum CloudType` to tell Jackson which value to use when reading/writing JSON. 
For that you also need a constructor to initialize this value.

Like this:

```
public enum CloudType {
    AZURE("azure"),
    OPENSTACK("openstack");

    private final String value;

    private CloudType(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then Jackson will serialize `CloudType.AZURE` to `"azure"`,
and deserialize `"azure"` to `CloudType.AZURE`.