# custom xml deserializer in jackson for enum

Tags: java, xml, kotlin, jackson

I'm have a lib's enum look like this:

```
enum class VatRate {
    none,
    tax10,
    tax20
}
```

**I can't modify this enum**. And I need to deserialize `VatRate` from xml like this:

```
<testXml>
  <vat>vat10</vat>
</testXml>
```

I know how to create and use mixins with jackson. But how to tell jackson to use external function for deserialisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do it on your own:

```
fun stringToVat(value: String): VatId { return VatId.valueOf(value) }
```

An easier way would be to define your expected DTO and let jackson do the unmarshalling:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "testXml")
data class TestXml(
    @field:XmlElement(required = true)
    var vat: VatRate? = null
)
```

**Edit**: You can register your own custom [Enum Serializer/Deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173645/5908014). Does this help?

Comment: I can't modify VatRate. How I can tell jackson which function should be used for deserialization?